# ks_2samp gives unexpected p-values

Tags: python, scipy

I want to compare two distributions using 2 sample K-S test.
I'm using python's (2.7) ks_2samp but I'm having some troubles.

First of all I don't understand if I have to put as parameters just the arrays with my data or to build a cumulative distribution of them. I guess the first one...

Secondly, when I use ks_2samp on my data, I obtain as return p-values that don't look realistic...

For example, for a couple of distribution that looks like this:
[CDF of 2 datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWKLh.png)

ks_2samp returns:
D-value = 0.038629201101928384
P-value = 0.0

That means that the distributions don't descends from a same one (roughly speaking). I think it is very strange for these data... It looks strange also a result like "0.0", because usually the task gives results with many decimals...
Using similar data in input I get for example p-value = 6.65e-136, that actually it's very strange.

What could be the problem? Or is it all right?

In my array there are many "nans", but I also run ks_2samp on data where I masked the nans, getting the same result. So I don't think it cares...

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I think the docstring (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) makes it clear that the arguments are your sample data (not CDFs).  What is the size of your samples?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser That's what I though. The results I gave are obtained using my data, that are arrays 500000 elements length (order of magnitude...). Could they be too big? Thanks!

Comment: (if cares: my arrays have many "nans", the "real" number of elements is one order magnitude lower)

Comment: `ks_2samp` is not designed to handle `nan`s, and it will probably give you an incorrect p-value.  You should remove them from your data before calling `ks_2samp`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser actually I masked nans and re-run ks_2samp on the masked arrays, obtaining the same result... Maybe I could try to completely remove these data from arrays... Thank you

Comment: Apparently `ks_2samp` doesn't handle masked arrays either.  Try it with clean standard numpy arrays.

Comment: ok @WarrenWeckesser I cleaned the arrays. Apparently I don't see particular differences on the p-values... they are the same order of magnitude than before, that in my opinion are very strange. The D-value on the contrary looks like more realistic... Anyway, thanks for helping

Comment: How many non-nan values do you have?  With enough data, even a slight discrepancy will result in a very small p-value.

Comment: in a sample 9000, in another 20000, in another 45000.

Comment: in the first case the "p" is 0.0 (but the two distributions are really different, with D=0.6 and more), in the second and first something e-150... (with D=0.1)